# Am trying to get chartin web page according to the graph value. but

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function (){
myFunc();

  });

  function myFunc(){

 if (document.getElementById('graph').value=10){

var chartData = [{"category":"Payment Details", "value1":10, "value2":90}];


var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "theme": "light",
    "type": "serial",
    "depth3D":100,
    "angle":30,
    "autoMargins":false,
    "marginBottom":100,
    "marginLeft":350,
    "marginRight":300,
    "pathToImages": "images/",
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "100%",
        "gridAlpha": 0
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "type":"column",
        "topRadius":1,
        "columnWidth":1,
        "showOnAxis":true,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "lineColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "fillColors": "#8d003b",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "valueField": "value1"
    },{
        "type":"column",
        "topRadius":1,
        "columnWidth":1,
        "showOnAxis":true,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "lineColor": "#cdcdcd",
        "fillColors": "#cdcdcd",
        "fillAlphas": 0.5,
        "valueField": "value2"
    }],

    "categoryField": "category",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "labelOffset":40,
        "gridAlpha":0
    }
   });}

   else if (document.getElementById('graph').value=20){

  var chartData = [{"category":"Payment Details", "value1":20, "value2":80}];


var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "theme": "light",
    "type": "serial",
    "depth3D":100,
    "angle":30,
    "autoMargins":false,
    "marginBottom":100,
    "marginLeft":350,
    "marginRight":300,
    "pathToImages": "images/",
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "100%",
        "gridAlpha": 0
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "type":"column",
        "topRadius":1,
        "columnWidth":1,
        "showOnAxis":true,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "lineColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "fillColors": "#8d003b",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "valueField": "value1"
    },{
        "type":"column",
        "topRadius":1,
        "columnWidth":1,
        "showOnAxis":true,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "lineColor": "#cdcdcd",
        "fillColors": "#cdcdcd",
        "fillAlphas": 0.5,
        "valueField": "value2"
    }],

    "categoryField": "category",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "labelOffset":40,
        "gridAlpha":0
    }
   });
 } 
  </script>
 <form:form method="GET" modelAttribute="xyz" action="xyz.htm" >
    <c:forEach items="${payouts}" var="payout" >
                        <tr>
     <input type="hidden" name="graph" id = "graph" value  
   ="${payout.graph}"/>     
 </tr>
```

Am trying to get a cylindrical chart in jsp using the graph value. but the chart is not displaying the value=20. only if case is executing even the graph value is 20

please suggest how to get the chart in jsp on th basis of the graph value

Comment: You have a typo `document.getElementById('graph').value=10` uses the assignment operator `=`. what you want is comparison operator `==` which makes it `document.getElementById('graph').value==10`

Comment: thank you.. i tried that but no result... same as before

Comment: Did you change your `else if` statement as well? Neither one are using the correct operator. What exactly is it not doing/doing? Throw in some debug statements to see what the value of `document.getElementById('graph').value` is.

Comment: yes i changed else if statement also using == . but i am getting the value of graph as 20 in page source of web page. but i dont know how to debug in script. am new to this

Comment: place `console.log("input value", document.getElementById('graph').value)` right before the `if` statement. You can view console values by hitting f12 in your browser and make certain you have it open when you load the page or you may not see the console values.You can also type js into the console to check values such as the hidden input `graph`.

Comment: for more info on debugging javascript see the [Chrome debugging tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging), [Mozilla debugging tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript) and/or [IE debugger tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: i wrote that before if statement and  i got input value 10 in mozilla console

Comment: can you give me the AMCHART CDN link which you are using??

Comment: when am changing value of graph in database the console log is showing the changed value.. yes the value of graph is getting perfect but i dont know why its not changing the chartview. yes i'll give the link http://www.amcharts.com/demos/cylinder-gauge/

Comment: no i am asking for CDN link, which you are refering in <script> tag.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/amcharts.js"></script>   are you asking about this?

Comment: Am new to this. so please dont mine. where CDN will be

Comment: if (document.getElementById('graph').value==10){....}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used the below statement. and it worked fine for me.

```
   if (document.getElementById('graph').value==10){....}
```